# QR Code won´t work although input is correct

Tags: php, pdf, qr-code, pdflib

At work we are using PDFLib to create personalized PDF files. This works fine so far, but now I have come to struggle.

I try to create VCards which are then converted to QR-Codes and printed on business cards for example.

While my function seems to work very nice ([find it here](http://pastebin.com/ibTt7NhV), use it, if you like it) the generated QR Code is unreadable.

I think this might be some problem with the integrated QR Code generator in our software solution (I don´t have access to that piece of software), but I need to verify this, before I go and blame the (external) developers for that.

I have used [this site](http://goqr.me/de/) to generate a QR Code from the function output (with the sample data provided in the Pastebin) and it works fine. I have also used about a dozen other online QR Code generators and about 10 or so worked fine, too.

It would be great if you have either some ideas, why the generator might fail to create a readable QR Code or if you can verify that my code works as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the QR code totally *unreadable*, or can't it just not be parsed correctly? Generate a code, make a screenshot, and submit it to online decoders that can show a binary dump. Then compare.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I tried that and it shows that some variables are not passed to the function. This seems to be some kind of PDFLib issue, I will update this post when I get to know more.